# Program doesn´t stop when asking for turning bluetooth on

Tags: android, bluetooth, dialog

I tried to use the dialog `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE` to ask the user for
turning bluetooth on, but when I used it, the Program didn´t wait for the dialog to end.
I have to know whether the user allows to turn bluetooth on or not, so that I can return to the previous activity if he won´t allow it. Getting the Result even using `onActivityResult` didn´t work.

How can I get the result of the dialog and how can I make the program wait for the result of the dialog?

The Dialog I tried to use:

```
private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 100;  
...  
Intent btEnable = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);  
startActivityForResult(btEnable, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

After that it just goes on without waiting for the result.

Comment: "Geting the Result with onActivityResult didn´t work too" -- please explain in greater detail what you mean by this sentence. What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: I just didn´t call the onActivityResult. I wrote it like it worked befor but the activity just goes on and didn´t waited for the result.

Comment: public void onActivitResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent Data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, Data);
 if(RequestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)....
}
This wasn´t called

Answer (score 0):

> but when I used it, the Programm didn´t wait for the dialog to end

It is not supposed to. `startActivity()` and `startActivityForResult()` are asynchronous.

> I just didn´t call the onActivityResult.

You don't call `onActivityResult()`. You implement `onActivityResult()`. It will be called when the user is done with the activity you started via `startActivityForResult()`. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

> public void onActivitResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent Data) { super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, Data); if(RequestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT).... } This wasn´t called

That's because you spelled the method name wrong. It is `onActivityResult()`, not `onActivitResult()`. Use the `@Override` annotation to help detect these sorts of issues.

> How can I get the result of the dialog

In `onActivityResult()`, see if Bluetooth was enabled.

> and how can I make the programm wait for the result of the dialog?

You don't. Android is event-driven; you handle the event via `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Now it works. I catch the result in the onActivityResult() and if the result is ok then i can start the next dialog in the onActivityResult().

onActivityResult()

Comment: I was to slow to finish this so now here is the rest of it:


//Global
REQUEST_CODE_1 = 0;
REQUEST_CODE_2 = 1;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent dialog = new Intent(myclass.this, dialog1.class);
    startActivityForResult(dialog, REQUEST_CODE_1);
}

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_1)
{
   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
   {
       Intent nextDialog = new Intent(...);
       startActivityForResult(nextDialog, REQUEST_CODE_2);
   }
}

if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_2)
{...}
}

Comment: Ok i will post the right thing in 6 hours so that i can do it as an answer and not as an comment...

Answer (score 0):

So now the right answer in code....

```
//Global  
REQUEST_CODE_1 = 0;  
REQUEST_CODE_2 = 1;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    Intent dialog = new Intent(myclass.this, dialog1.class);  
    startActivityForResult(dialog, REQUEST_CODE_1);  
}  

onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
{  
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_1)  
{
   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)  
   {  
       Intent nextDialog = new Intent(myclass.this, nextDialog.class);  
       startActivityForResult(nextDialog, REQUEST_CODE_2);  
   }  
}

if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_2)  
{...}  
}
```